# Consecutive Occurances

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a attendance tracker screenshot below every 5 consecutive personal or sick days counts as 1 occurrence. I was hoping for an array formula that counts consecutive days then restarts if not consecutive, but i am at a loss with how to even begin to count them. Do i need to change my table or is there a way to get this done.

I tried Array formulas I think VBA might be the best way.

I think i could get it done if i used numbers or dates but i was hoping to be able to use the P or the S
[image]

Comment: What happens with weekends?  i.e. if Employee 1 is Sick on Friday and Sick on Monday, will Saturday and Sunday also be "S"?

Answer (score 3):

You could use SCAN for this task:

`=SUM(N(SCAN(0,B5:Q5,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(OR(y={"P","S"}),x+1,)))=6))`

[image]

This produces a counter `A in the picture` if a cell value within the range equals either "P" or "S".
If it finds consecutives it raises the count by one each time up to there's no consecutives found; then it resets to 0.

This array of this counter-spill is checked for presence of 6 and returns TRUE or FALSE per value, which is converted to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE) by the numeric representation of this boolean `B in the pic`.

If we sum this `C`, we get the count of at least 6 consecutives.

---

With older Excel we could use:
`=SUMPRODUCT(N(FREQUENCY(IF((B5:Q5="P")+(B5:Q5="S"),COLUMN(B5:Q5)),IF((B5:Q5<>"P")*(B5:Q5<>"S"),COLUMN(B5:Q5)))>5))`

*I think SUMPRODUCT enforces it to become an array formula, but not sure if entering with `ctrl+shift+enter` is required because of FREQUENCY.*

---

*PS if you want to reset the count if 6 consecutives are found (so you want 12 consecutive P or S to count as 2 occurences), you could use this:*
`=SUM(N(SCAN(0,B5:Q5,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(OR(y={"P","S"}),x*(x<6)+1,0)))=6))`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Disclaimer: It's late, so I might be overcomplicating this - so there are probably massive improvements and optimisations/simplifications to make…)</sub>

To count the number of different chains of "S", you can do the following:

1. Join all of the values together into a single chain, with [the `CONCAT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2) or [`TEXTJOIN` functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) (`CONCAT($B5:$AF5)`)
2. Use [the `SUBSTITUTE` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) to replace all "V"s or "P"s with their opposite value (`SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P")`)
3. Use `SUBSTITUTE` *again*, along with [the `REDUCE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reduce-function-42e39910-b345-45f3-84b8-0642b568b7cb) and [`LAMBDA` functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) to turn consecutive chains of the delimiter into a single value (`REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"PP","P")))`)
4. Split *that* on your delimiter, to get an array that contains all consecutive chains of "V": (`TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"PP","P"))),"P")`)
5. Count how many items are in the array, with `COUNTA`:

```
=COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"PP","P"))),"P"))
```

That will tell you how many chains there are of consecutive appearances of "S".  If you need to know, the total number of *any* chain, then you add together the "S", "V" and "P" values:

```
=COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"PP","P"))),"P")) + COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"P","S"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"SS","S"))),"S")) + COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"S","V"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"VV","V"))),"V"))
```

Or, if you want to know what length of the longest chain of Sick Leave is, then you take the `MAX` of the `LEN`gth of the values in the array, instead of just counting them:

```
=MAX(LEN(TEXTSPLIT(REDUCE(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT($B5:$AF5),"V","P"),TEXTSPLIT(REPT("|",99),"|"),LAMBDA(a,b,SUBSTITUTE(a,"PP","P"))),"P")))
```

(Step 3 may look complicated, but it basically does a really long chain of `SUBSTITUTE`, so that the values "SVS", "SVVS", and "SVVVVVVVVVVS" all turn into "SVS" - because, we don't care about the "V"s, except for having 1 between each chain of "S"s)